# Phpdoc documentation with php activerecord

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, phpdoc, phpactiverecord

I'm using [php-activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) for a short while now and i absolutely love it. Php-activerecord is an open source ORM library based on the [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern. However, i also like [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) and use that to document my code. Therefore it's easy for my coworkers to understand the platform's i build. But with php-activerecord in use my Model classes now look like this:

```
/**
 * The Company class.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 */
class Company extends \ActiveRecord\Model
{
    /** explicit table name since our table is not "company"  */
    static $table_name = 'Company';

    /** explicit pk since our pk is not "id" */
    static $primary_key = 'companyId';
}
```

They work, but they used to look like this:

```
/**
 * The Company class.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 */
class Company extends \ActiveRecord\Model
{
    /** @var integer The company id. */
    private $companyId;

    /** @var string The company name. */
    private $name;
}
```

**Long story short**

With php-activerecord in use there's no way to document my model attributes and update phpdoc. I want to be able to do this, in what direction should i look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can document all your "magic" properties as an `@property`! Say you have a table "Company" with fields "id, name, location", you would end up with:

```
**
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $location
 */
class Company extends \ActiveRecord\Model 
{

}
```

You can see [in the documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) that there are some other tricks, like "property-read". I use those for any connections you might have, as you can read a has-one for instance, but cannot write models to those connections.

So if a Company has employees that you have defined as a `$employees`, you might add

```
* @property-read Employee[] $employees
```

and so on.

Comment: This looks great, i'm gonna try this :-) Nice.